# convert model to array and return as json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How do I get a model from the database and then convert it to an Array including extra information using the with statement.

```
public function edit($id) {
    // convert product to array;
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id)->with('supplier', 'category');

    $data = [
        'suppliers' => Supplier::all()->pluck('company', 'id'),
    ];        

    // cannot merge because $product is object and cannot turn into array
    // the only way I know to convert to array is doing this
    // $product->first()->toArray() but this gets the first item in the database
    $product = array_merge($product, $data);

    return response()->json($product, 200, ['Content-Length' => strlen(json_encode($product))]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Laravel's collection helper to make it simple:

```
collect($product)->toArray()
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
$product array_merge(collect($product)->toArray(), $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$return = [
    'suppliers' => Supplier::all()->pluck('company', 'id'),
    'product' => $product // or $product->toArray()
];

return response()->json($return, 200);
```

If you need the suppliers to be an attribute of the product, you could try this:

```
$productArr = $product->toArray();
$productArr['suppliers'] = Supplier::all()->pluck('company', 'id');

return response()->json($productArr, 200);
```